# How to resize a broad image correctly?

Tags: logo

I got a logo from a design agency:

[image]

In my website there is only room for a logo image in the size of `160px X 160px`, so after I have uploaded the logo image to my website, I got:

[image]

How to solve that unproportionality problem?
How to resize a broad image correctly?

Comment: A link to my website: https://hanekudai.com/index.php/%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93%D7%90%D7%99

Comment: You are changing the aspect ratio of the image. That is why it is squished. When you rescale an image, make sure you enable the option that says "preserve aspect ratio" - sometimes this shows as a little link icon in some software.

Comment: Seems like your website is managing both, the width and height of the image when uploaded. You can do something with your css or javascript if you're doing multiple logos. In your case, for just one logo, you can use inline css and set only the width of the image. The height will adjust itself. For best results, I think, it would be better to use a graphics program to make the adjustments and follow @Scott's answer before uploading.

Answer (score 2):

You size to **best fit** while keeping the logo *proportional*.

Keep the *canvas* at 160x160px, but if the logo (proportionally) only fills 160x100px, that's the size you use on the canvas.

[image]

*Logos* should **always** be sized proportionally. *Always.* One should *never* squish, stretch, or squash any logo for any reason.