# How to resize a broad image with GIMP?

Tags: gimp, resize

I use GIMP 2.10.32 and I have a large broad image of about `1600px width X 1000px height` and I need to resize it to about `160px width X 100px height`.

How to resize a broad image with GIMP?

I think there is a function for that named "**best fit**" but I am not sure.

Comment: This thread is a follow up for: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/158207/how-to-resize-a-broad-image-correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `Image > Scale image` it will by default keep the "aspect ratio" (if you set a value for width, Gimp will computer the corresponding height and vice-versa).

[image]

Height/width can be made independent by opening the chain link to the right of the two fields.

If you use the Scale tool ([image]) this is the opposite, by default the aspect ratio is not kept, but you can force the tool to keep it in the tool options (or by depressing the shift key while resizing). However, you probably don't want to use the scale tool for this.

In any case, if you scale down to 160px it will look bad because you have many less pixels... In addition you can have problems caused by [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing). A counter-intuitive way to fix this is to blur the image before scaling down, to remove the details that won't be visible anyway (smaller than a pixel). In your image, at 160px the space between the "X" and the "T" will be about a pixel, so you can blur until this space is hardly visible. Then you scale to 160px:

[image]

You can even apply a bit of Sharpening (`Filters > Enhance > Sharpen`):

[image]

Finally, your image was likely created as [vector graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics)(.AI or .SVG), and a better solution would be to generate a 160px bitmap image directly from that.

Comment: I did it with "Scale image" and breaking the chain etc. but sadly the result is very "smusshy" or "nudgy", it doesn't look very good to me... It looks, "pixelated". Perhaps there is some way to "prettify" it a bit.

Comment: See edited/augmented answer...

Comment: Thanks a lot, how do I blur the image before scaling it down and sharpening it?

Comment: `Filters > Blur > Gaussian blur`

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Fast Stone Image Viewer](https://www.faststone.org/). A very powerful yet lightweight image viewing, organizing, and editing tool.

Also [PowerToys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) has a built in Image Resizer that's surprisingly competent. Regardless of whether it can help your needs now, it's a great app to have and provides at ton of QOL improvements to windows.

Lastly for a more plug and play service, check out [Autowaifu](https://autowaifu.azurewebsites.net/). A great app that easily automates the process of upscaling digitally-drawn 2D images and animations.